# Will batsman be run out if the ball ricochets off short leg/silly point fielder *before* he can play at it?

Tags: rules, cricket

Consider a typical situation when a batsman steps out of the crease against a spin bowler to play an attacking shot. However, the ball turns very sharply (due to pitching into a footmark/crack and/or exceptional skill of the bowler), and hits the short leg or silly point fielder (not his helmet), then ricochets on to the stumps. The ball hit the fielder *before* it crossed the batsman. In such case, would the batsman be run out?

Of course, if the fielder deliberately "snatches" the ball, it would be considered as significant movement distracting the batsman, and the umpire would call no ball. However, if it happens accidentally, this won't apply.

See below illustration.

```
.....+-----SSS-----+    S - stump
.....|       @     |    B - batsman
.....+-----@-------+    F - fielder
.....|   @         |    @ - ball trajectory
.....| @    B      |
....@|             |
..F..|             |
....@|             |
.....| @           |
.....|   @         |
.....|     @       |
```

Comment: AFAIK, if the ball touches the fielder before it comes to the batsman, it is called as dead ball. And batsmen may not score runs or be given out. I can't find any law for the given situation (because this is almost impossible physically). I have submitted a query to lords.org lets wait for the reply.

Comment: I would call it dead ball as well, under Law 23.4(b)(vi).

Comment: It should cross the stumps otherwise dead ball

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is **Not out**.

The Umpire at the bowler's end should call *No Ball* and immediately call *Dead Ball* under Law 24.7. The ball is not to be counted in the over and should be bowled again. Any further  action beyond the call of *Dead Ball* is to be ignored.

For more clarity check out: [law-24-in-action](http://www.lords.org/mcc/laws-of-cricket/laws-in-action/law-24-in-action)